# Creating Gmail labels with Japanese characters

Tags: utf-8, gmail-api

I've got some code to create labels in Gmail, which usually works fine. But now the requirement is to create a label with Japanese characters, specifically "アーカイブ". I am encoding the json like this:

```
7B 0D 0A 22 6E 61 6D 65 22 3A 22 E3 82 A2 E3 83   {.."name":".....             
BC E3 82 AB E3 82 A4 E3 83 96 22 2C 0D 0A 22 6D   ..........",.."m             
65 73 73 61 67 65 4C 69 73 74 56 69 73 69 62 69   essageListVisibi             
6C 69 74 79 22 3A 22 73 68 6F 77 22 2C 0D 0A 22   lity":"show",.."             
6C 61 62 65 6C 4C 69 73 74 56 69 73 69 62 69 6C   labelListVisibil             
69 74 79 22 3A 22 6C 61 62 65 6C 53 68 6F 77 22   ity":"labelShow"             
0D 0A 7D 0D 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ..}.............
```

As you can see, the first character is the UTF8 sequence E3 82 A2, which if you look at this table (https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=12352&names=-) seems to be correct for that first character.  The others look OK also.

As a test, I created a Japanese folder with that name in the UI, then got a dump of the json that Gmail produces when I get a list of existing folders. What Gmail produces is exactly the same as what I'm trying to import.  So I don't see what I could be doing wrong here.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hi there @JeffMcKay! I don't understand how you need help with the Gmail API since you said *`What Gmail produces is exactly the same as what I'm trying to import`*, could you please clarify what you need? Also please share any error messages if you got them.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind this - turns out my Japanese characters translate to "Archive" which is apparently a reserved folder name.